# cursor pagination mongodb mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Any mongoose and mongo experts out there that can help me out? As the title says I wanna try and implement cursor based pagination. I've seen an old post here about it but I'm trying to see how I can get the second set of posts.

I get this part

```
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

But how do i apply this second part. Am i suppose to create a separate route for this?

```
const items = db.items.find({
  _id: { $lt: req.query.next }
}).sort({
   _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement this in 1 route, using `skip` and `limit`.

Like so:

```
const skip = Number(req.query.skip ?? 0);
const limit = Number(req.query.limit ?? 2);
const items = db.items.find({}).sort({
    _id: -1
}).skip(skip).limit(limit);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

Now for the next page you'll want to send a request including these new query params:

```
https://myapp.com/myroute?skip=2&limit=2
```

---- EDIT ----.

using the `next` object id for skipping instead of `skip`, like so:

```
const filterQuery = {};
if (req.query.next) {
    filterQuery._id = {$lt: ObjectId(req.query.next)}
}
const items = db.items.find(filterQuery).sort({
    _id: -1
}).limit(2);

const next = items[items.length - 1]._id
res.json({ items, next })
```

And the call would be:

```
https://myapp.com/myroute?next={{itemId}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do i get the next page after the second? And what is the point of having next if im not using it to get the next query?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean,  the names of the parameters can obviously change from skip to next if that's it?.
To get the "next next" page you just need to increase the `skip` to 4.

Comment: sorry let me be more specific. I have an instagram style app with infinite scroll. It would be hard to accurately skip over posts if users create a post. I wanted to use the ```next``` which is set to the next id as reference point so that either i wont skip over it or have duplicates.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I edited my answer.

Comment: Hey Im on postman and its not allowing me to get the next call with ```{{}}``` its invalid syntax. Also I have my items sorted by date. I just tried pasting my date in after ```https://myapp.com/myroute?next=``` and it doesnt work either =(

Comment: next should be a valid ObjectId, what's ```{{}}```? obviously it's invalid.
Your route should look like:
https://myapp.com/myroute?next=6177c268e4590a6ab3e33039

Comment: Just switched it over to use ```_id``` and with the same route but when i request next, it just gives me an empty object. Says 404 not found

Comment: 404 is an app level error, you should make sure your calling the first route properly, the only addition to is the query param part `?param1=value1`.

Comment: if i do ```https://myapp.com/``` it shows the first 2 posts. When i try ```https://myapp.com/myroute?next=6178630aad548ecdd9e162d9``` thats when i get the 404.

Comment: Why are you adding myroute to the second call?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need to be more specific. My route that fetches the posts is ```http://localhost:1337/``` when i call this route, I fetch the data. To get the next two i did ``````http://localhost:1337/?next=6178630aad548ecdd9e162d9``` and it didnt work. Am i suppose to add something to my routes? In my current setup i use ```const {page} = req.query``` and get posts using ```http://localhost:1337/?page={{1 or 2 or 3, etc....}}```. My apologies once again, I'm a beginner ambitious to learn cursor pagination.

Comment: `localhost:1337?next=6178630aad548ecdd9e162d9`. should work. at the very least it should not give a 404 but a code error.

Comment: yea still returns empty object, 404 not found. I most likely dont have something setup right. I'm gonna try and debug it. Thanks again!

Comment: I think its this syntax ```ObjectId(req.query.next)``` because when i hard code the actual id, it fetches more data

Comment: Great, so just solve it to match and it'll work